Importance sampling with relative weight from two histograms
I have two datasets of real values, $X = (x_1, \dots, x_N)$ and $Y = (y_1, \dots, y_M)$. Here $Y$ is a subset of $X$. These data points can be regarded as samples from some unknown densities, $x\sim p(\cdot)$ and $y \sim p(\cdot|A)$, respectively, where $A$ is some restrictive condition.
In particular, we can assume that $p(x|A)$ non-zero implies that $p(x)$ is also non-zero. Indeed, considering the two possibilities that $A$ is either true or false, we have that $p(x) = p(A)p(x|A) + (1-p(A))p(x|\text{not } A)$, where $p(A)$ is the probability that $A$ is true.
I am interested in estimating an integral of the form:
$$I = \int \frac{p(x|A)}{p(x)} f(x) \mathrm{d}x$$
However, I don't know the form of the densities $p(x)$ or $p(x|A)$. I also may not know the value of $p(A)$, though perhaps I can estimate it easily. Intuitively I think I will need $p(A)$ to have an estimate of $I$. Besides that, suppose that the only thing I have access to are the samples $X = (x_1, \dots, x_N)$ and $Y = (y_1, \dots, y_M)$.
Can we use the samples $X = (x_1, \dots, x_N)$ and $Y = (y_1, \dots, y_M)$ to construct an estimate of $I$ ? If needed, suppose we also know $p(A)$.
Please feel free to edit the title of this question, I wasn't sure how to call it.
